# which one is right, "see" or "seen" in the sentence below?

Tags: usage

Which one is right "see" or "seen" in the sentence below?
I should've tried a regular size first and then see/seen if I'd need more.

Answer (score 1):

**"I should've tried a regular size first and then SEE if I'd need more."**

**Present Tense:** see -
(the action is happening NOW in the present)
**Example:**
"I see you" (something you say in the exact moment it happens and it is something you would use in first person)

**Past Participle:** seen -
(used with have, has, is, was, will be, had been, etc.)
**Example:**
"I've seen beautiful things"
(again only used in first person context) usually used in case of reflecting on a memory (something that has already happened)

**Remember:**
The word 'seen' must never follow directly after the words I, he, she, we, they, (any person’s name).